# Section author to be shown in footer

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr, thesis

For my diploma thesis I need to write the author of each text section in the footer, to make visible who wrote that exact part.

In comparison to Microsoft Word (I hate to do that u.u) you can enter continuous section breaks and set individual headers and footers for each section.

How can I achieve something like that in LaTeX?

Edit: Added MWE (I used this template https://github.com/novoid/LaTeX-KOMA-template but reduced it to what you see here)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{Graphics}
\lfoot{<<<Section Author here>>>}
\rfoot{\thepage}

%Redefine chapter by adding fancy as the chapter title page page-style
\makeatletter
    \let\stdchapter\chapter
    \renewcommand*\chapter{%
    \@ifstar{\starchapter}{\@dblarg\nostarchapter}}
    \newcommand*\starchapter[1]{%
        \stdchapter*{#1}
        \thispagestyle{fancy}
        \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}
    }
    \def\nostarchapter[#1]#2{%
        \stdchapter[{#1}]{#2}
        \thispagestyle{fancy}
    }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Section by Author 1}
Some text...

\section{Section by Author 2}
Some more text...

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this case, it really matters, for example, which class you are using and how you are currently formatting headers/footers.

Comment: Hi and welcome, can't you just use `\cfoot{you}` and `\cfoot{the other guy}`? It seems we need [a bit more information](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) to avoid guesswork like that.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve something like that in LaTeX. But it depends on your set up. Please, provide an MWE.

Comment: @Johannes_B I just realized that I can use \cfoot or \lfoot inside my document (I thought I'd have to define it for the whole docoment)
If you post it as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please avoid using `fancyhdr` with KOMA-script. *Please*.

You can use the commands to set header and foot multiple times. Depending on where you are in the text, you might want to use a `cleardoublepage`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,
    headsepline%
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{Graphics}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

%Using `fancyhdr` with KOMA is discouraged
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}
%\chead{Graphics}
%\lfoot{<<<Section Author here>>>}
%\rfoot{\thepage}
%



%This is just disgusting. DO NOT DO THAT!
%%Redefine chapter by adding fancy as the chapter title page
%%page-style
%\makeatletter
%\let\stdchapter\chapter
%\renewcommand*\chapter{%
%   \@ifstar{\starchapter}{\@dblarg\nostarchapter}}
%   \newcommand*\starchapter[1]{%
%       \stdchapter*{#1}
%       \thispagestyle{fancy}
%       \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}
%   }
%   \def\nostarchapter[#1]#2{%
%       \stdchapter[{#1}]{#2}
%       \thispagestyle{fancy}
%   }
%   \makeatother
%

\newcommand{\setauthor}[1]{\ifoot*{#1}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Section by Author 1}
\setauthor{Author Aides}
\blindtext[15]

\section{Section by Author 2}
\setauthor{Author Bides}
\blindtext[8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll raise an issue with the tempalte maintainers concerning the fancyhdr business. Nevermind, the template does not use `fancyhdr`.

Comment: yeah, I'm quite new to latex and so I've done some mistakes (I've already found a way to avoid the chapter redifine [I've found this solution on some other stackexchange thread])
Sadly I don't have the time to rework my document at the moment, but once I have time I'll try to implement your solution :)